# Shopify ThemeKit: after deploy I loose all saved fields

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to customize a theme in Shopify, using Theme Kit.

Everything was good since I noticed that after I run the command theme `deploy --allow-live`, I loose all the values of the custom fields saved on Shopify.

So, for example this is the code of my file 'homepage.intro.liquid':

```
<div class="image">
    <a class="banner-opacity" href="#"><img src="{{section.settings.intro_one_img | img_url: '470x570'}}"></a>
</div>
```

And this is a part of the schema:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Homepage Intro",
    "settings": [
      {
        "id": "intro_one_img",
        "type": "image_picker",
        "label": "Immagine 1"
      },
      ...
{% endschema %}
```

So this is what I'm doing:

1. I go to Customize Theme in the Shopify Admin, I can upload and select an image without any problem and everything is working.
2. After this, let's say I need to add a file or a folder to my theme but it's not correctly uploaded on the Shopify admin.
3. So, I stop the 'theme watch' and then I run `deploy --allow-live`.
4. The file or folder is correctly uploaded.
5. The image I uploaded at point 1) is not selected anymore.

And this happens with ALL the fields... and not only images but even text fields.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your deploy overwriting the `config/settings_data.json` file with old data? If so, you may want to add that file to the ignore list in your config.yml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `config/settings_data.json` to Theme Kit `config.yml`:

```yaml
development:
  password: shppa_123
  theme_id: "123"
  store: xyz.myshopify.com
  ignore_files:
  - /config/settings_data.json
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now it does not erase my fields anymore after deploy, but it works for me writing just "settings_data.json" and not "/config/settings_data.json"

Comment: So if you add /config/ before file name it won’t work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **ignores** instead of **ignore_files** in the config.yml file.

```
development:
  password: shppa_123
  theme_id: "123"
  store: xyz.myshopify.com
  ignores:
  - .themeignore
```

And then in the .themeignore file for example:

```
# GULP
node_modules

config/settings_data.json
```

Makes it easier to ignore multiple files and folders. Check this link for the official documentation: https://shopify.dev/themes/tools/theme-kit/configuration-reference#ignore-patterns